# Copy folders with certain string in name to one directory and without that string to another directory

Tags: string, batch-file, directory, robocopy

I'm looking for a way to copy with a batch file subfolders from one folder path (*C:\Example*) to another folder path *D:\Example_ABC* if the string "ABC" is contained in the subfolder. If this string is not contained in the subfolder it should be copied to *D:\Example_noABC*.

The original folder path *C:\Examples* contains subfolders in the way

```
- B123
- B099
- B939
...
- ABC_A990
- ABC_B099
- ABC_I000
```

Is there any easy way to do so?
I tried to achieve it with robocopy but this seams only to work with file names but not folder names.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to realize what I want to do with the help of robocopy but it's not very nice. Since many people asked similar questions on the internet and nobody provided a really sufficient solution, I'd like to post my solution here:

I first look for all the folders that contain ABC and copy only those to the destination *D:\Example_ABC* and then robocopy all folders except those that contain ABC with a normal robocopy to *D:\Example_noABC* The XD command does the trick here (exclude directory)

The code is as follows:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir C:\Users\example\ABC*. /ad /b') do robocopy C:\Users\example\%%a D:\Example_ABC\%%a /e /v /np /w:1 /r:1 /xo

robocopy C:\Users\example\ D:\Example_noABC\ /e /np /w:0 /r:0 /xo /xd ABC*
```